# Why is it easier to add bromine to styrene than cinnamic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why is it easy to add bromine to styrene and why is it so difficult to add bromine to cinnamic acid? It is obvious that the $\ce{COOH}$ group of cinnamic acid affects the reaction quite a lot, but I just can't figure out why. I am guessing that the electronegativity and inductive effect of the carboxylic acid plays a key role. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. We like to keep questions neat and to the point without any distractions like "Greetings", so I edited your question accordingly. I hope to see your question answered soon. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe consider doing some research into alpha beta unsaturated carbonyl compounds.

Comment: Right now I seriously have the same question as you do @christofer!